# Scientific Calculator in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, radians

I am making calculator with c# language with visual studio. I have a problem with 
converting radians to degrees. I'm currently doing it like this:

```
display.Text=(Math.cos(Convert.ToDouble(display.Text)*( 180 /Math.Pi ))).ToString();
```

But the results (in degrees) of my calculator are different from the results I get from the windows calculator.

Comment: Why is this a java question?

Comment: Is that the correct calculation?  When you step through each individual component of that calculation, where specifically does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Why is Math.cos needed?

Comment: i want to convert cos of specific value like cos(user input) but c# giving the answer in radians, and my question is how to give the answer in degree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this shouldn't be a Java Specific question. Secondly, a quick google search could have given you this answer

Including this one -> [SCIENTIFIC CALCULATOR USING C-SHARP(C#.NET)](https://allcodes4web.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/scientific-calculator-using-c-sharpc-net/), which basically covers all the scientific functions you're looking for including the Radian to Degree conversion